# Can this be rewritten as a has_many through association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am doing some rails association practice and I have the following associations

```
class User
   has_many :videos
end

class Video
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
end
```

The way how it is above makes sense to me. I want to get the following:

```
user1 = User.find(1)
user1.videos  #A user's associated videos
user1.comments #A user's associated comments
user1.videos.first.includes(:comments) #A particular user video's comments
```

This seems acceptable to me but something tells me that this could potentially be better. Is there a potential `has_many :through` association as in "A user has many comments through videos?" I don't think that would be a correct association because a comment can't have many users through videos. Can I use a "has_many :through"That only goes one direction?

Comment: Is it your intent that users own videos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you're missing `User.has_many :comments`

```
class User
   has_many :videos
   has_many :comments
end

class Video
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :video
end
```

If you want to find a particular user's comments on particular video...

```
user.comments.where( video: video )
```

Or vice versa.

```
video.comments.where( user: user )
```

---

Note that `User.has_many :videos` is a bit odd. Do users own videos in addition to commenting on them? I think it may have been your intent to have `user.videos` be the videos the User has commented on. In that case...

```
class User
  has_many :comments
  has_many :commented_videos, through: :comments, class_name: "Video"
end
```

And now you can get the videos the user has commented on.

```
videos = user.commented_videos
```

Note that I've avoided calling this association simple `:videos` to make it clear these are the videos the user has commented on, not the user's videos.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User
   has_many :videos
   has_many :comments, through: :videos
end

class Video
   has_many :comments
   belongs_to :user
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :video
end
```

Try above associations if it fulfils the expected behaviour.